# Is there anyway of getting Realm objects modified according to date without having to explicitly add a date as a property?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I would like to be able to retrieve the set of objects not modified since before a specified date.
Of course I can easily add the date as a property of my custom object and use that.
However the database could contain hundreds of thousands of records and the addition of a date field to each of them will increase the size.
So I was wondering if there is some internal date or modified flag or some trick to be able to do this without having to add an explicit date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Realm does not internally track the modified time for objects.